# stringWithFormat: with unknown datatype

Tags: objective-c, nsstring, foundation

I am making a framework and I have this code (`conditions` is an NSDictionary):

```
for (NSString *key in conditions) {
    id value = [[conditions valueForKey:key] retain];


    // Check if number or string
    if ([value class] == [NSString class]) {
      conditionsString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@='%@' ", key, value];
    } else {
      conditionsString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@=%@ ", key, value];
    }
  }
```

If the `value` is an NSString, quotes should be added, otherwise codes should not be added. However, if not an NSString, I don't know the datatype of `value`, as it could be NSNumber, NSInteger, int, float, double, etc... I can't just use `%@` or `%d` but I'm sure someone on SO knows how to do this? Thanks.

Comment: you cannot add a `NSInteger`, `int`, `float`, or `double` to a NSDictionary because they are all C structs. You can only have Objects of type `NSObject` as @nesium has said.

Comment: Aha, so all numbers should be an NSNumber?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

have a look at [this](http://jens.ayton.se/blag/almost-elegant-cave-man-debugging/).

edit: in your case it's pretty easy, since nsdictionary can only contain nsobjects. so %@ would do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

You could check the class (kindOfClass) and then use appropriate formatter.

e.g.

```
if ( [myObj isKindOfClass:[NSString class]] )
```